# Wrong behavior when editing and another one already edits the post

Tags: discussion, bug, edits

1. `Alice` starts editing a post
2. `Bob` edits the post
3. `Bob` finish the editing
4. `Alice` sees the notification that the post was edited and click to reload the post.
5. `Alice` wants to close the browser tab.

She gets the notification that her edit is not saved.

I guess this is another little bug on the client side... Am I right?